# My android webview style not same as mobile view

Tags: android, wordpress

I create webview from Android studio, and my website is wordpress website when I look on mobile view it look perfect, but when look in apk file design it different carousel can't move slide not working, and can't click on the link

Comment: Edit your question and add the code that you have tried.

Comment: https://github.com/javaddehban/SimpleWebViewAplication

Comment: @JavadDehban this one work but need some help, when  i click on mobile link it show unknow url but in mobile view it just show dial number , Any idea?